# How to add items to sharepoint list from a html document?

Tags: javascript, html, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am trying to create a comments section in a sharepoint site. Is there anyway I can use javascript to read some text from a 'div' or a 'p' element and then add that item into a list when the user press submits?

Some examples of codes would be much appreciated.

Also can you try and only give javascript examples please and not jquery.

Thak you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of work you can use Sharepoint JavaScript Client Object Model. Please read about it from:

[How to: Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

there is not much differences in basic operations between 2010/2013 but be aware.